# How to convert selected file byte array to base64 in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need call api with parameter input is base64 format file, so when I choose the file from client i want to convert it to base64 in Angular.

Comment: Js version: https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/ed9j7epr/

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as [DataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

```
onFileUpload(event: any) {

    let file = event.target.files[0]
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)

    fileReader.onload = () => {
        // You'll get the base64 string here
        console.log("base64 :", fileReader.result)
    }

    fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        console.log("Error reading file :", error)
    }

}
```